# Reuse static method for Function mapping

Tags: java

Using Play, the controller class has several methods with the pattern:

```
public static Promise<Result> getFoo() {
    Promise<Response> resp = WS.url("/api/foo").get();
    return resp.map(new Function<Response, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(Response arg0) throws Throwable {
            String body = arg0.getBody();
            return Results.ok(body);
        }
    });
}
```

I considered creating seperate mapping function:

```
private static Function<Response, Result> mapResponse = new Function<Response, Result>() {
    @Override
    public Result apply(Response arg0) throws Throwable {
        String body = arg0.getBody();
        return Results.ok(body);
    }
};
```

So that I can then reuse this in multiple static methods:

```
public static Promise<Result> getFoo() {
    Promise<Response> resp = WS.url("/api/foo").get();
    return resp.map(mapResponse);
}

public static Promise<Result> getBar() {
    Promise<Response> resp = WS.url("/api/bar").get();
    return resp.map(mapResponse);
}
```

Intuitively I think this may cause problems as multiple methods will be reusing the same static mapping method, but I realized that I am not sure of the actual behavior. I am wondering if reusing a static variable could bottleneck concurrent calls, or the JVM will automatically instantiate multiple copies to handle processing in different methods.

What are the drawbacks of such an approach, or will it actually work properly? If not, what are my options to reduce the boilerplate mapping code used in multiple methods?

*Note: I don't think the question above is actually specific to Play but is more of a generic Java coding question, hence not using Play as a tag.*

Comment: I don't see any problem. Why wouldn't it work? You're reusing a stateless, and thus immutable, object in several methods. Immutable objects are inherently thread-safe.

Comment: @JBNizet: I was concerned about multiple method invocations trying to reuse the same function variable - updated question to indicate that. Mostly, I guess its just a case of I haven't used this before and am not clear of JVM behavior :/